# how to Sending Email with a PDF Attachment laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, email, pdf

I have this function, but I cannot declare the generate to pdf

How do I generate PDF and send e-mail in PDF?

I have sent an email, but the one sent is in html format.

```
public function store_banegosiasi(request $request,$id){
        if(!Session::get('login')){
            return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
        }
        else{
        $idp = $request->id_penyedia;
        $sesi = Session::get('id');  
             DB::table('tbl_paket_pl')
              ->where('id_paket_pl',$id)
              ->update(['status_undangan_pl' => $request->status_undangan_pl]); 

            $data = new ModelUndanganpl();
            $data->id_paket_pl              = $request->input('id_paket_pl');
            $data->hari_pl                  = $request->input('hari_pl');
            $data->tanggal_pl               = $request->input('tanggal_pl');
            $data->bulan_pl                 = $request->input('bulan_pl');
            $data->tahun_pl                 = $request->input('tahun_pl');
            $data->sph_pl                   = $request->input('sph_pl');
            $data->negosiasi_teknis_pl      = $request->input('negosiasi_teknis_pl');
            $data->save();

        $nama = DB::table('tbl_profile_penyedia')->where('id_profil_penyedia', $idp)->pluck('nama');
        $namapp = DB::table('users')->where('id',$sesi)->pluck('name');
        $hari = $request->hari_pl;
        $idundangan = DB::table('tbl_undangan_pl')->pluck('id_undangan_pl');
        $sph = $request->sph_pl;
        $nt = $request->negosiasi_teknis_pl;
        $pl = DB::table('tbl_paket_pl')->where('id_paket_pl',$id)->pluck('nama_pesanan_pl');
        $pesanan = DB::table('tbl_pesanan_pl as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_bmn2 as b', 'a.kode_bmn', '=', 'b.kode_bmn')
        ->join('tbl_paket_pl as c', 'a.id_paket_pl', '=', 'c.id_paket_pl')
        ->join('tbl_profile_penyedia as d', 'c.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'd.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->join('users as e', 'd.id_user', '=', 'e.id')
        ->join('tbl_kriteria as f', 'c.id_kriteria', '=', 'f.id_kriteria')
        ->join('tbl_paket as g', 'd.id_paket', '=', 'g.id_paket')
        ->join('tbl_pagu as h', 'c.id_pagu', '=', 'h.id_pagu')
        ->join('tbl_pembayaran as i', 'c.id_pembayaran', '=', 'i.id_pembayaran')
        ->join('tbl_ruang2 as j', 'a.kode_unit', '=', 'j.kode_ruang')
        ->join('tbl_jenis_penyedia as k', 'd.id_jenis_penyedia', '=', 'k.id_jenis_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_kategori_belanja as m', 'g.id_kategori_belanja', '=', 'm.id_kategori_belanja')
        ->join('tbl_cabang_ut as l', 'd.id_cabang_ut', '=', 'l.id_cabang')
        ->where('a.id_paket_pl',$id)
        ->get();
        $email = DB::table('tbl_profile_penyedia')
            ->where('id_profil_penyedia', $idp)
            ->pluck('email');
        $tanggalh    = $request->tanggal_pl;
        $bulanh      = $request->bulan_pl;
        $tahunh      = $request->tahun_pl;
        Mail::to($email)->send(new BANegosiasiMail($nama,$namapp,$hari,$idundangan,$sph,$nt,$pl,$pesanan,$tanggalh,$bulanh,$tahunh));
        return redirect('pesanan')->with('success','Berhasil Dikirim!');
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things but it hasn't worked, can you help me

can you help me do it,please help me

Comment: I hope this will help https://dev.to/sandeepbalachandran/how-to-generate-pdf-and-send-it-on-mail-in-laravel-5-8-b8j

Comment: an error occurred @Azhar

Comment: please show the error